# How to update NSLayoutConstraint constants, that have previously been set in code? - Swift

Tags: ios, swift, autolayout, nslayoutconstraint

I'm trying to completely make my view programatically. It has a bottom view that animates up when a search query finishes with the relevant information. I've set the .bottom nslayoutconstraint of the bottom view to an optional nslayoutconstraint, first initialising it off screen in     override func viewWillLayoutSubviews().

```
    let bottomView = UIView()
    var bottomViewBottomConstraint: NSLayoutConstraint!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    view.addSubview(bottomView)

}

override func viewWillLayoutSubviews() {

    //Bottom View Constraints
    bottomView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    let bottomViewLeftConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: bottomView, attribute: .left, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: view, attribute: .left, multiplier: 1, constant: 0)
    let bottomViewRightConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: bottomView, attribute: .right, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: view, attribute: .right, multiplier: 1, constant: 0)
    let bottomViewHeightConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: bottomView, attribute: .height, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: nil, attribute: .notAnAttribute, multiplier: 1, constant: 75)
    bottomViewBottomConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: self.bottomView, attribute: .bottom, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: view, attribute: .bottom, multiplier: 1, constant: 100)

    NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
        bottomViewLeftConstraint, bottomViewRightConstraint, bottomViewBottomConstraint, bottomViewHeightConstraint
        ])
   }
```

The view appears up once the search query is complete.

```
                self.view.layoutIfNeeded()

            UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.8, delay: 1, usingSpringWithDamping: 1, initialSpringVelocity: 0.1, options: .curveEaseIn, animations: {
                    self.bottomViewBottomConstraint.constant = -5
                    self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
                }, completion: nil)
```

However after that point, when I try to dismiss the view, and change the NsLayoutConstraint's constant, the view doesn't move.

```
    self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
    UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.8, animations: {
        self.bottomViewBottomConstraint.constant = 100
        self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
    })
```

In the output console, I'm getting this error and I'm not sure how to fix it.

```
    Make a symbolic breakpoint at UIViewAlertForUnsatisfiableConstraints to      catch this in the debugger.
    The methods in the UIConstraintBasedLayoutDebugging category on UIView   listed in <UIKit/UIView.h> may also be helpful.
    2016-10-11 14:50:01.768353 Green Homes Australia[973:232019]   [LayoutConstraints] Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints.
        Probably at least one of the constraints in the following list is one you don't want. 
    Try this: 
        (1) look at each constraint and try to figure out which you don't expect; 
        (2) find the code that added the unwanted constraint or constraints and fix it. 
(
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x17028d6b0 UIView:0x1049365b0.bottom == UIView:0x100b04e40.bottom - 5   (active)>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x174681cc0 UIView:0x1049365b0.bottom == UIView:0x100b04e40.bottom + 100   (active)>")

    Will attempt to recover by breaking constraint 
<NSLayoutConstraint:0x174681cc0 UIView:0x1049365b0.bottom == UIView:0x100b04e40.bottom + 100   (active)>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that your

```
override func viewWillLayoutSubviews() {
```

runs again and again and again. Layout happens a lot! Thus, those constraints all get created and added again and again, including *after* you have done the animation and changed the bottom constraint. So you end up with two conflicting bottom constraints. (You actually have *lots* of bottom constraints, but all the others are equal to one of the the conflicting constraints so the runtime doesn't complain.)

A simple solution that I like to use is to put a boolean flag so that my initial configuration only happens once:

```
var didConfig = false
override func viewWillLayoutSubviews() {
    if !didConfig {
        didConfig = true
        // create and configure constraints here
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, your a lifesaver, thought it only ran at runtime.

Comment: I had the same effect and resolution even when bootstrapping the constraints in a custom `setup()` method.  My classes' subclasses were overriding the method and calling `super.setup()`, which re-bootstrapped the constraint with inconsistent values.  Resolved by setting my bootstrap setup method to `private`, eliminating the multiple calls.